# Elasticsearch "self-join" type operation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index containing documents that look something like this (unnecessary fields omitted)

```
{
 _id: String,
 ...
 relatedIds: [ String ]
}
```

The `relatedIds` are recursively referring to the `_id` of the documents themselves.

I want to write a query that will return only the id's from the `relatedIds` array that are not an `_id` of a document.

In abstract, I want to grab all of these identifiers, perform some computation, so that in the end every id in the `relatedIds` refers to a document in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your id field is also contained in the source document, you can do it like this:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "relatedIdsLessId": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "doc. relatedIds.values - doc.id.value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will compute a new field named `relatedIdsLessId` which will only contain the related IDs which are not the ID of the document itself.

Note: you need to make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) if not already done.

Comment: Inline scripts are disabled by default.

Comment: I haven't been able to try this out yet as mentioned above inline scripts are disabled by default, and I don't have access (currently) to the config file for the ES I'm targeting.